# Uncaught TypeError: ReactDOM is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

> Hi everyone,I have some issues with my React Code and i can't use the ReactDom because the console says that 'Uncaught TypeError: ReactDOM is undefined'.
> This is my code and begins with my first component AddTasks :

```
    import { useState } from "react"
    import ShowOrDelete from "../ShowOrDelete"
    import React from 'react'

    const AddTasks = () =>{
        const [tasks, setTasks] = useState('')
        const placeHolderText = "Escribe algo aqui"
    

    return(
        <div className="bg-slate-200 p-8 mt-36 m-auto w-1/2 h-96 rounded-lg text-2xl text-center" id="task-container">
            <h2 className="mb-8"><strong>Mis Tareas</strong></h2> 
            <div>
                <input className="h-10" type="text" name="tasks" id="input-value" placeholder={placeHolderText}/>
                <ShowOrDelete insertTasks={setTasks} tasks={tasks}/>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
    }

    export default AddTasks
```

> Next this is the next Component that must to render and where i have the issue.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'



const ShowOrDelete = ({ insertTasks, tasks }) =>{
    const addTasksToComplete = () =>{
        const input = document.getElementById('input-value').value;
        insertTasks(input)
        const tasksDiv = <div className="bg-slate-950 text-white text-xl"><p>{tasks}</p></div>;
        ReactDOM.render(
            tasksDiv,
            document.getElementById('task-container')
        )
    }

    return(
        <div className="inline">
            <button onClick={() => addTasksToComplete(insertTasks, tasks)} className="bg-green-500 text-white text-xl p-2">Agregar Tareas</button>
        </div>
    )
     }


    export default ShowOrDelete
```

> But then in the console of the localhost show me the message of the title. So what i can do to resolve this or what is the issues?

Comment: Which version of `react` and `react-dom` do you use?

Comment: Why are you using that in the first place?

Comment: It looks like you wanted to use a react portal instead

Comment: It's a personal exercise to practice React

Comment: Well you starting to get off track. I'd suggest to follow a official tutorial like tic-tac-toe: https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe

Comment: "react": "^18.2.0",
 "react-dom": "^18.2.0". This are the version that i'm using

Answer (score 0):

Only your `index.js` should contain a `ReactDOM.render()`, all deeper components should just render there UI by providing a `return()`.

Same goes for `document.getElementById`, you should only use that once in `index.js` to get the React root element, in deeper components, those `getElement**` function are almost always a bad idea

---

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Component1 = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            I'm Component - 1!
            <Component2 />
        </div>
    )
}

const Component2 = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            I'm Component - 2!
            <h3>I don't use ReactDOM, I just return what to render!</h3>
        </div>
        
    )
}

// This is in Index.js
ReactDOM.render(<Component1 />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```